# Convert plain string to time

Tags: java, string, date, time

I have a String value which I need to convert into time and save it in the MySQL.[The column's datatype is time in the database table]
The examples of String values that I might encounter to convert into time object are:

> String time = "5:32 PM";
>
> String time = "12:00 AM";
>
> String time = "11:43 PM";

I browsed for few examples which pulled the time from the Date object but couldn't find an apt example, such as in this case to convert it from a plain string. The main reason I need to convert it to time is to save it in the mysql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert it to  `java.sql.Date`  as :

```
String str = "5:32 PM";
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
java.util.Date date = (java.util.Date)formatter.parse(str);
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
```

If you need `java.sql.Time` , then :

```
java.sql.Time time = new java.sql.Time(date.getTime());
```

And then use [PreparedStatement#setTime()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setTime%28int,%20java.sql.Time%29).

Comment: `java.sql.Date` does not store time, you should use `java.sql.Time` or `java.sql.Timestamp`. Still, the best would be using plain `java.util.Date` since these three classes from `java.sql` package extend from it.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Please add that to the answer , that is valuable comment :)